# CSS Transform scale, don't scale child element

Tags: css, transform

If I have a div with a few child elements and it's being css transform scaled. I've got one child element which I don't want to scale

```css
#parent{
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
}
 
span:last-child{
    -webkit-transform: Something to ignore the parent scale;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <span>Child 1</span>
    <span>Child 2</span>
    <span>Child 3 (Don't Scale Me)</span>
</div>
```

Can this be done with css only? Without changing the html or using js.

Comment: That is not possible, scaling affects an element and _all_ its content. Only thing you can do is scale the child “back” by the appropriate factor.

Comment: Could you, instead of scaling, change the width of the parent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

You roughly have two other options though:

1. Scale all the other elements, excluding the one you don't want to scale (but this won't scale the container).
2. Scale the container and re-scale the element you don't want to scale (but this will probably make it look blurry).

Examples:

```
// Example 1.
span:not(:last-child) {
    display: inline-block; /* You can't scale inline elements */
    transform: scale(2);
}

// Example 2.
#parent{
    transform: scale(.5);
}

span:last-child{
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: I can attest re: #2 that this will definitely make it look blurry. I need to do something similar for a PDF viewer. Without using scaling the main scrolling eleemnt will get too large with long documents, but I want to render the viewport to the actual screen pixels without regard to scaling. 
I was thinking of using an absolutely positioned element above the scaled one but this presents other issues.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you need to use a more detailed selector, like this `#parent > span:not(:last-child)`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dc1999f9/).

Answer (score 1):

I found [**hack**](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/transforms-cause-font-smoothing-weirdness-in-webkit/) for Chrome to solve problem with blurred.

```
#parent { transform: scale(5);}
#child  { transform: scale(0.2)  translate3d( 0, 0, 0);}
```