# make div NOT scalable

Tags: html, css

is there a way to make a div not scalable?

This is my css:

```
.card{
margin-left:5px;
width:19%;
float:left;
}
```

I want the div card to stay the same width even when you scale the browser.

Comment: Don't use a percentage in `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a percentage only if the container of your div element has a fixed width in pixels. Or, as Oriol told you, use a fixed width for your div

Answer (score 0):

If you just set your width using `px` and not `%` it will max it to that width

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8ccvwhg/)

Comment: This does not work if the width should be always 1/5 of the screen width... I have the same problem with a sticky top menu having width:100%, but I don't want to have it scalable...

Answer (score 0):

The [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) property

> specifies the [content width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#content-width) of boxes.

It can have those values:

> - [`<length>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length): Specifies the width of the content area using a length unit.
> - [`<percentage>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-percentage): Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's
>     [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block).
> - `auto`: The width depends on the values of other properties.

You are using a percentage. Use a fixed [length](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length) instead:

> The format of a length value is a [`<number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-number) (with or without a
>   decimal point) immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., px,
>   em, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You could target children of a parent no to scale by css selectors, but you cant disable scaling as a property on a single element unfortunately.

```
#parent > span:not(:last-child){
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
    display:block;
}
```

See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051600/css-transform-scale-dont-scale-child-element)