# Scale parent element but remove scaling on child elements

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on some css animation using `scale`. Is there a way to restrict child elements not to scale and only the parent element will scale.

```css
.scale {
    max-width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    background-color : beige;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin : top left;
}

.scale:hover {
    -webkit-transform : scale(2.0);
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
 }
 
.scale:hover .dont-scale {
    -webkit-transform : scale(1.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="scale">
    <div class="dont-scale">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>    
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Transform scale, don't scale child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051600/css-transform-scale-dont-scale-child-element)

Comment: Why are you using prefixes? [Transition](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) & [2D Transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) have very good support across browsers. Prefixes are not needed in this case.

Answer (score 4):

> `.scale:hover .dont-scale {}` run after `.scale:hover {}`,so scale(1) Measure than scale(2) ,for this reason child will be scaled same parent.

**Try This :**

```
.scale:hover .dont-scale{
    -webkit-transform : scale(0.5);
    transform : scale(0.5);
}
```

> To avoid margins issue:

```
.dont-scale{
   -webkit-transform-origin : top left;
   -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}
```

```css
.scale {
  max-width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  background-color : beige;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin : top left;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
  transform-origin : top left;
}

.dont-scale{
  -webkit-transform-origin : top left;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
  transform-origin : top left;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.scale:hover {
  -webkit-transform : scale(2.0);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
  transform : scale(2.0);
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
 }
 
.scale:hover .dont-scale{
  -webkit-transform : scale(0.5);
  transform : scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="scale">
  <div class="dont-scale">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that before, but it seems to be having some imaginary margins. Take a look at my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/clestcruz/Lg32f3sa/

Comment: To avoid margins issue, add this css, .dont-scale{ -webkit-transform-origin : top left;-webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;}

Comment: @ShyamBabuKushwaha  , Thankyou.